# Category not refreshing after including file in functions

Tags: wordpress

I am making a custom wordpress theme and noticed that when i include a file in the functions file, the categories stop refreshing. I need to refresh the page for the new category to appear.

If i move the content of the file to the functions file everything is normal again.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind.

Don't know what i did wrong but now it's all good. just remake the file and included in the functions and now its working right.

Thanks anyway.